# Application failed codesign verification

Tags: iphone, code-signing

I installed xcode 4.2 and i'm trying to archive my second app. I didn't have any problem with my first (xcode 4.0.2) but now I'm getting the following error:

warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)

I've tried different things but nothing works. any suggestion?
thanks

Comment: xcode 4.2 and iOS 5 are under NDA - if you want to discuss do it on the apple dev forums.

Comment: sorry I didn't know that. I've seen it's a "common error".... when you install a beta version....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had this issue a couple times and it always has been that I have the wrong Code Signing Identity set in Build Settings. Check you've got the correct certificates selected for the correct profiles? (Developer Profile to Developer Build and Distribution/Release Profile for Release Build)

Also check your Code Signing Identity Certificates for the Project Build Settings and also the Code Signing Identities for the Active Target. Sometimes you set the correct certificates for one but the other has something different set. This has tripped me up a couple times too

Once you find the issue, do a Clean and then Build to ensure everything is flushed out.

Just to note, this isn't solely a Xcode 4.0.2 issue.

Comment: still not working and now also my first app shows the same error when I try to archive it.

Comment: Life saver. Its amazing how many small steps there are to the whole publishing process. My god.

Answer (score 1):

Mattia worked around his issue by reinstalling a GM version of Xcode (this is one of Apple's suggested fixes for the issue) however for others experiencing the error **"Application failed codesign verification"**, see Apple's complete list of potential causes at the following URL ["How do I resolve the error: Application failed codesign verification?"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG32)

Answer (score 0):

That's what I did to solve the problem:

1. cancel all my certificates and provisioning files and requested new ones.
2. uninstall xcode 4.2
3. reinstall xcode 4.0.2
4. create a new project and move all the files in the new project.
5. project VALIDATED!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  My app has a long history dated back to the old days of Xcode 3, in which case the scheme for distribution is called "Distribution".  In Xcode 4, "Distribution" is no longer used and Archive is using "Release" scheme.  So my fix is to check the certificate under "Release" instead of "Distribution".  For some reason, after I upgraded to Xcode 4.2, the certificate for "Release" is changed to a wrong certificate.