# Xcode codesigning (failed) warning : App Store rejected?

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, code-signing

I have an error that I can't solve... I correctly registered as an Apple Developer, been approved by Apple, obtained Development and Distribution certificates and WWDR intermediate certificate.

Correctly set the details, info and parameters of my app in iTunes Connect.

My app works perfectly, no error nor warning with the simulator or test devices. But when I archive it with Xcode for submission, I have this error :

> Application failed codesign verification. The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)

Two questions :

- Any idea of why I get this, and how to get rid of it ?
- If I submit my app to Apple with this warning, will my app be rejected for sure ?

Thanks for your advices !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Application failed codesign verification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726653/application-failed-codesign-verification)

Comment: I know it's a duplicate, except for the "Wil Apple reject it" I didn't see anywhere else.

Comment: Well apple won't accept an app that isn't codesigned if that's what you mean.  In fact, you can't even upload the binary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning implies that you have not set the correct certificates under codesigning within the app itself.

If you have downloaded your certificates, imported them into x-code, and selected them under codesigning in buildsettings and are still getting this error you should try re-downloading them.  I have seen this error on more than one occassion when everything was set correctly and simply doing it again fixed it.

As for your second question you won't be able to submit the app at all without fixing this.